# C++ "expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token" error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have this code:

```
FILE *f = fopen(intPath, "r");
Node *n;
if (f) {
    try {
        n = parse(f, intPath);
    } catch (SyntaxError e) {
        fclose(f); /***** line 536 *****/
        throw LangException(
            builtin_classes::exception_class::create_ImportError(
                String::fromAscii(e.filename)->
                append(String::fromAscii(":"))->
                append(String::fromInt(e.line))->
                append(String::fromAscii(":"))->
                append(String::fromInt(e.col))->
                append(String::fromAscii(": syntax error: "))->
                append(String::fromAscii(e.message))
        );
    }
    fclose(f);
    return n->eval(scope);
} else {
    throw LangException(
        builtin_classes::exception_class::create_ImportError(
            String::fromAscii("failed to open file for reading")
        ),
        line,
        col
    );
}
```

And the compiler gives this error:

> nodes.cpp:537:40: error: expected primary-expression before `‘(’` token
>   nodes.cpp:544:94: error: expected `‘)’` before `‘;’` token

I have no clue what it could be, especially since that code sample has another statement which does the same thing, and it doesn't cause an error.

Comment: What, you don't have time to format it properly?

Comment: Also, in future, please make a proper testcase. We have no idea what these `LangException`, `builtin_classes`, `String` types are and your code is invalid on its own (even not considering the errors you're here about).

Comment: I'm disappointed that here is a guy that's been around for 9months, and still posts questions of that quality.

Comment: @Johannes: Given only 48 rep, I'd say s/he probably doesn't come here often. That he came here for the first time 9 months ago means nothing.

Comment: @Martinho having sent 12 questions already, he should be more familiar with this. There's a "preview" box, where he can see how his question will come out. Even the greatest noob can insert line-breaks to reasonably format his code. There's no need to indent code 16 characters deep to make it even more ugly. I'm sorry, that's way too much incidents. And I don't believe girls can be that tasteless.

Comment: @mtk358 Just because the compiler doesn't error on both instances, doesn't mean it won't when you fix this one.

Comment: @Xaade I had more instances of that code before it. @Johannes Schaub I don't see anything too bad about how my code was formatted. And who are you calling a girl?

Comment: The big problem everyone probably had with the code was how much leading whitespace there was.  Did you notice: we could not see the code in the question without scrolling a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
throw LangException(
   builtin_classes::exception_class::create_ImportError(
      String::fromAscii(e.filename)->
      append(String::fromAscii(":"))->
      append(String::fromInt(e.line))->
      append(String::fromAscii(":"))->
      append(String::fromInt(e.col))->
      append(String::fromAscii(": syntax error: "))->
      append(String::fromAscii(e.message))
   )  // This closes the function call
; // You didn't close the throw here!
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `(` and your `)` don't match in that large, first `throw LangException` block.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tells you what is wrong.  The `throw LangException(` doesn't have a `)`.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what it says. You are missing a `‘)’` before `‘;’` token on that line.

```
LangException(...
```

is not closed.